# Arquivo POM.xml do Maven iniciando com erro no Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

Olá, sou novo no mundo Java e tenho enfrentado diversos problemas para criar um projeto Maven com o eclipse. Abaixo, colocarei o erro, seguido do meu arquivo Maven e a descrição das tecnologias que estou usando e o que já tentei fazer:

Erro: Could not initialize class org.apache.maven.plugin.war.util.WebappStructureSerializer (aparece assim que crio o projeto)

Maven:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
    child.project.url.inherit.append.path="">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>br.com</groupId>
    <artifactId>helloWord</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>
            UTF-8
        </project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

IDE: Eclipse EE Version: 2021-03 (4.19.0)
JRE 1.8 (Também tentei usando a 16 default do meu sistema)
Linux Fedora 32

Não instalei o Maven na minha máquina, somente instalei o eclipse e comecei a usar.
Já tentei:

Trocar a versão do JRE;
Criar outro projeto;
Reinstalar o eclipse algumas veze;
Apagar o diretório .me2 com os plugins do Maven para ele recriá-lo

Estou lendo a documentação mas não consigo resolver isso. Alguém pode, por favor, me ajudar?

Answer (score 0):

Tente o seguinte, baseado na [documentação](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html).

No POM.xml dentro de properties, adicione:

```
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
```

Já no plugin, deixe apenas:

```
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
```

Ficaria:

```
... trecho anterior ...

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

... trecho seguinte ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Para resolver este erro adicione a propriedade abaixo no final de eclipse.ini e reinicie o eclipse:

> --illegal-access=permit

Após isso se persistir o erro faça "Close Project" e em seguida "Open Project" no projeto desejado.